# pyqt - Updating widget text from function from different file

Tags: python, function, user-interface, pyqt

I have created gui form using qtdesigner and converted in to python code using pyuic4. Sample of my main script is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from PyQt4 import QtGui
from multibootusb_ui import Ui_Dialog
import sys
import os
import another_file_function
class AppGui(QtGui.QDialog,Ui_Dialog):

    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self)
        self.ui = Ui_Dialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.close.clicked.connect(self.close)
        another_file_function.function2()

    def function1():
        self.ui.text_label.setText("some text")
    function1()

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = AppGui()
ui = Ui_Dialog()
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

To make it easy i have created different function in different file. So that it can be accessed at any time by any scrips.

Here is the sample of function from another_file_function:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

def function2():
  #code here
  self.ui.text_label.setText("some text")
```

The function1 from main script and function2 from another_file_function are same. Also I am calling function2 from main class. The problem is that when i use `function1()` from main script it updates the GUI text without an issue. However, if i use the same function in different file and call that function from main script it fails to update and i get `global name 'self' is not defined` error.

Where am I getting wrong? Any help is appriciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am unclear why `function1` works either, I am going to assume it has a `self` in it's definition that you dropped.

To get `function2` to work you need to do something like:

other file:

```
def function2(input):
    #code here
    input.ui.text_label.setText("some text")
```

main file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from PyQt4 import QtGui
from multibootusb_ui import Ui_Dialog
import sys
import os
import another_file_function
class AppGui(QtGui.QDialog,Ui_Dialog):

    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self)
        self.ui = Ui_Dialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.close.clicked.connect(self.close)
        another_file_function.function2()

    def function1(self):
        self.ui.text_label.setText("some text")
    function1()

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = AppGui()
another_file_function.function2(window)
window.function1()
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Ok. You are correct i forgot to include self. However when i run the script after modification still i get `object has no attribute 'ui'`. If you can offer some explanation it would help me to understand the concept. This is just a request.

Comment: It means the object you are working on has not attribute 'ui'.  Edit your question to show what you are trying now.